# Get a count by clicking and display it in the Google Analytics Report

Tags: google-analytics

I have made a website and inserted the tracking code in the head tag.

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m
{i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'MYID', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Additionally, I want to know how many times users have clicked on each element. So I just added a little bit of code inside a tag as follows.

```
<label for="modal-toggle" id="order-btn" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'linkclick', 'clicked', 'open_modal_from_btn']);"></label>
```

However, I don't see any event information about labels on the report page.
I know JavaScript a bit. I think that it is weird the "_gaq" does not get initialised, and this might cause the unexpected result.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use GTM with GA, what ever your are asking its already present and very easy to implement